# Cambiar Color Input Al escribir numero

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo un `<input type="number">`. Necesito que por medio de **JavaScript** se realice un cambio de color al escribir un numero específico:

Ejemplo:

- Si escribe 0 = verde
- Si escribe -0 o -10 : morado
- si escribe de 1 a 10 : rojo
- Si escribe Mayor a 30: verde

Comment: Edita por favor y agrega lo que lleves al momento, te recomiendo además leer [ask], finalmente que hagas el [tour] para comprender mejor de que va SO en español y tu pregunta pueda permanecer abierta

Comment: Haz intentado algo en tu JavaScript, edité tu pregunta para que se viera mejor pero por favor agrega el código JS con el que haz intentado resolver el problema

Comment: No señor no eh realizado el JavaScript

Comment: No es difícil programar lo q pides, y hay varias formas de hacerlo. Pero en SO no respondemos preguntas q no demuestran un interes por parte de la persona q pregunta. Intentalo, y si tiene problemas durante tu desarrollo, nos consultas un error en especifico.

Answer (score 2):

```js
//selecciono el input number por el id
input = document.getElementById('miNumero');
//escucho el evento keyup
input.addEventListener('keyup', validar);
//funcion donde valido mi lógica
function validar(event){
   //si el valor es 0
 if(this.value == 0){
   input.style.backgroundColor = "green";
  //si el valor es entre 1 a 10
  }else if( this.value > 0 && this.value < 11){
    input.style.backgroundColor = "red";
  //si el valor es mayor a 30
  }else if(this.value >30){
    input.style.backgroundColor = "green";
  //si el valor es negativo
  }else if(this.value <0){
   input.style.backgroundColor = "purple";
  }
}//end function validar
```

```html
<input type="number" id="miNumero" name="miNumero">
```

**Explicación**

Lo primero que debes hacer es obtener el `input` en este caso uso el `ID` para identificarlo.

Ahora con esto debes escuchar el evento `keyup` para saber que teclas presiona y obtener dicho valor y realizar tu lógica deseada, en este caso invoco a una función `validar`.

Esta función valida mediante `if` las condiciones que necesito y mediante:

```
input.style.backgroundColor = "green";
```

defino un color de fondo `backgroundcolor` deseado para cada condición.

para mayor detalle sobre el evento keyup te sugiero revisar: [KeyUp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/keyup_event)

Comment: Me puedes ayudar Tengo los datos ya mas organizados :
Si es +30 tenga el Color #68AB5C
Si es entre 11-29 Color #FFF301
Si es entre 0 -10 Color # FF0000
Si es Menor que 0 Color # AE0FF

Comment: simplemente cambia los colores de ingles por los codigos hexadecimales que tienes ahora y te funcionara perfecto..ejemplo cambia "green" por "#68AB5C" y asi sucesivamente..!

Comment: Muchas Gracias Bro Eres Un master

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
    at inner.html:9